# Ошибка 400 при открытии страниц в IE, Firefox, Google Chrome

Tags: браузер

Добрый всем день.

У меня такая проблема. Сначала перестало открываться видео из  сайтов. Просил установить плагин flash plaer, пытался установить, пишет: "Ошибка установки. Попробуйте еще раз". Удалил с помощью винда ХР эту прогу, попытался заново её установить - тот же результат. После этого выход в инет с любого браузера выдает ошибку 400. Даже с нового установленного на флэшке.
Почта и обновление антивируса загружаются. Кто может помочь?

Comment: @АнатолийФ, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Comment: Возможно вирус что-то напортил, у меня был какой-то ютюбСкачиватель - антивирус предупредил и удалил. Перестал инет работать, он вроде есть, а его нет... Возможно, восстановление системы нужно сделать.
А вообще проще Линукс поставить, например, Альт Линукс (с KDE и Xfce для выбора) - вирусов нет, стабильности и гибкости больше.

Answer (score 1):

Чаще всего причины следующие:

1. Глюки у провайдера (звоните в тех. поддержку).
2. Сетевое оборудование (модем, точка доступа, etc - для начала перезагрузить).
3. Блокирует антивирус (отключить его и все, что с ним связано).
4. Вирусы (маловероятно, если антивирусные базы актуальны).
5. Брендмауэр Windows (отключить его и все, что с ним связано).
6. Кэш и куки браузера (в данном вопросе, наверное, не актуально, но почистить/удалить все же стоит).

Как вариант, попробуйте Live-cd дистрибутив какой-нибудь системы для проверки.